# unistd read() doesn't work

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unistd.h

I am trying to write / read text files using the unistd library. I will later deploy it to a file in the / dev path.
I'm trying to use `std::vector` type instead of `char buffer[]`. So I wrote two implementations, one using vector and another char buffer. Both write well in the file, but neither can read the file.

Here is my test code:

using buffer of char

```
void tests_using_buffer_of_char(const std::string &path)
{
    int file_descriptor_char;   
    char buffer[8] ={0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    std::cout << sizeof(buffer) << std::endl;       

    for(auto i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
        std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;

    file_descriptor_char = open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR);
    if(file_descriptor_char != -1)
        std::cout << "open with success " << path << std::endl;

    std::size_t size = strlen(buffer);
    ssize_t write_bytes = write(file_descriptor_char, buffer, size);
    std::cout << size << " <-- size of buffer " << write_bytes << " <-- size of writed bytes" <<  std::endl;

    memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));

    ssize_t read_bytes = read(file_descriptor_char, &buffer, size);
    std::cout << size << " <-- size of buffer " << read_bytes << " <-- size of readed bytes" <<  std::endl;

    for(auto i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
        std::cout << buffer[i] << std::endl;

    if(close(file_descriptor_char) != -1)
        std::cout << "close with success "<< path << std::endl;
}
```

using buffer of vector

```
void tests_using_buffer_of_vector(const std::string &path)
{
    int file_descriptor_vector;
    std::vector<char> buffer = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
    std::cout << buffer.size() << std::endl;

    for(auto i : buffer)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    file_descriptor_vector = open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR);
    if(file_descriptor_vector != -1)
        std::cout << "open whit success " << path << std::endl;

    ssize_t write_bytes = write(file_descriptor_vector, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
    std::cout << buffer.size() << " <-- size of buffer " << write_bytes << " <-- size of writed bytes" <<  std::endl;   

    buffer.clear();     

    ssize_t read_bytes = read(file_descriptor_vector, buffer.data(), write_bytes);
    std::cout << buffer.size() << " <-- size of buffer " << read_bytes << " <-- size of readed bytes" <<  std::endl;    

    for(auto i : buffer)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    if(close(file_descriptor_vector) != -1)
        std::cout << "close with success " << path << std::endl;

}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `unistd` isn't a library, it's a C header on POSIX systems. And you probably shouldn't write "*xy* doesn't work" when you know *xy* is a *standard function* working for millions of programmers just fine and you're probably just using it wrong.

Comment: You are right! Thank you for the advice. On a next question I will be more precise and less generalist about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] Just use `fclose` and reopen the file.

2] `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);`

3] `rewind(fp);`

You are pointing to the end of the file with `file pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset your file descriptor to be at the beginning of the file before trying to reuse it for reading after you used it for writing. You could close the file and reopen it, or you can seek to the beginning.

```
lseek(file_descriptor_vector, SEEK_SET, 0);
```

Don't clear your vector before reading into it. the `clear` method will essentially deallocate the memory associated with the vector.